# Assign the value to checkbox from db in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am new to datable.
In `db` I have a `boolean variable` named `Paid` based on this if it is 1 checkbox should be active and 0 unchecked. I have tried some piece of code .

```
"render": function(data, type, full) {
    if (data.Paid == 'false') {
        return '<div class="checkbox alignCenter check-control" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">' +
            '<label class="check " onclick="event.stopPropagation();">' +
            '<input type="checkbox" id="cbInvoicePaid_' + (index++) + '" class="cbInvoicePaid" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" autocomplete="off">' +
            '<span class="cr tab checkfocus"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>' +
            '</label>' +
            '</div>'
    }
}
```

Comment: any console error/problem, what is your question?

Comment: No console error problem if do like this datatable is not displayed

Comment: you say paid value shall be 0 or 1 whereas you are comparing to data.Paid == 'false'

Comment: Not like that if data.paid is false i want checkbox to be unchecked and if it is true checked state

Comment: You want to check uncheck `cbInvoicePaid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used mdata instead of mData in datatable so i wasn't able to get the data correctly.